# Are there suspensions or fines for exaggerating contact or flopping to draw fouls in football (soccer)?

Tags: rules, football, fifa, uefa

In professional football (soccer) matches, players often exaggerate contact or flop to draw fouls.  What actions (suspensions, fines) are soccer organizations, including FIFA or UEFA, doing to prevent this?

Comment: As an aside: If I'm not mistaken, basketball calls this type of behavior "[flopping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flop_%28basketball%29)." The NBA charges $5,000 USD to first-time offenders for flopping.